# SQL How to correctly use TRY/CATCH/THROW statement and Next

Tags: sql, try-catch, ssms, throw

I am trying to utilize a **TRY/CATCH/THROW** statement with SQL but I am unfamiliar with exactly how to input everything for the most efficient code, as well as what code would be paired with each of those methods.

My current code is

```
BEGIN TRY
    Insert Into ENT_ITEM_MASTER
    from Sheet1$
    WHERE ITEM_CODE = ENT_ITEM_MASTER
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    If ITEM_CODE <> ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        THROW;
END CATCH;
```

What I want it to do is that if `ITEM_CODE <> ENT_ITEM_MASTER` then it will skip that item code and go to the next one.

If someone could explain how to correctly throw that exception and add a little detail of what exactly `CATCH` and `THROW` do so I could better understand what exactly they are used for, that would be incredibly helpful.

I have a linked server to an Excel file with 16,000 rows of information. My code inserts that info into an item list. It links with another program so that, if I search for an item code, all of the info on it will come up.

**EDIT** to address answer. Trial code:

```
Insert Into ENT_ITEM_MASTER
from Sheet1$
WHERE ITEM_CODE = ENT_ITEM_MASTER


If ITEM_CODE <> ENT_ITEM_MASTER
    Insert Into ENT_ITEM_MASTER
    from Sheet1$
    WHERE ITEM_CODE = ENT_ITEM_MASTER
Else
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a try/catch/throw is necessary? It appears you could do a for loop that loops for each row with a nested if statement inside to check If ITEM_CODE <> ENT_ITEM_MASTER. If the condition is met then 
    Insert Into ENT_ITEM_MASTER
    from Sheet1$
    WHERE ITEM_CODE = ENT_ITEM_MASTER
Else ( ). Does that make sense?

Comment: If that is a better way then absolutely! I was told TRY/CATCH was the best so I was just basing my trial/error off of that. Does the code I have input in the question above look correct? I am not very familiar with SQL so I do not know if I need an End If statement or parentheses or just if it is formatted correctly @Hayes

Answer (score 0):

After rethinking through your problem I believe a case statement is best.

Try:
 CASE WHEN ITEM_CODE = ENT_ITEM_MASTER THEN 
     Insert Into ENT_ITEM_MASTER
     from Sheet1$
     WHERE ITEM_CODE = ENT_ITEM_MASTER
 END

Comment: that doesn't seem to mention where `ITEM_CODE <> ENT_ITEM MASTER`. Would that take care of that or is there something else I am supposed to implement in addition to that? @Hayes

Comment: If I understand it correctly you do not intend to perform any action when ITEM_CODE <> ENT_ITEM_MASTER. If that is correct then it should be taken care of. If you do intend to perform a command when they are not equal you could add an else before the end.